# NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest completion call order

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

It's not highlighted in the docs, neither clearly in any question here. Does `NSURLConnection` use operation dependencies internally? I mean two subsequent calls to `sendAsynchronousRequest` will execute their `completionHandler` in the order of initial calls OR according to real completion of their tasks?

Comment: They shouldn't be if it isn't documented. I haven't tested it but I'd suggest that it isn't linked. You can test it. If it is linked it should be raised as a bug anyway....

Comment: @Wain visually they are linked, but I havn't test it accurately.